# Is there a way to keep file structure when using Photorec?

Tags: macos, data-recovery

I keep getting folders that are just piles of items. I need the original structure of the recovered files.

Comment: More information as to why you feel the need to use Photorec as ..."PhotoRec ignores the file system and goes after the underlying data, so it will still work even if your media's file system has been severely damaged or reformatted." which means you should be happy to just get files. There might be a better tool to meet your need...

Comment: I see. I am very happy to get my files back, but it somewhat defeats the purpose if I can't have the original file structure. I'm using OSX 10.6.8 and photorec was the only recovery software I could find that didn't cost anything. Are there any reccomendations?

Comment: Edit your question explaining your issue e.g., accidentally deleted a partition and would like to restore it...files

Answer (score 0):

No. If you want to recover file system (folders files etc.) then you need to use other tools, which can repair the file system itself. Filesystem and files are stored in different places on the disk. As file system keeps records of where to find files and to which directory do they belong to, files are simply somewhere on the disk and can be fragmented or not. Photorec simply is trying to find files and makes sense to use, if file system is not repairable. (so directories are lost)